# Application of Riesz Representation Theorem on $C[a,b]$

Tags: real-analysis

Let $f$ be a function in $C[a,b]$ norm with $\|f\|_{max}=\max_{x\in [a,b]}|f(x)|$, how to find a function $g$ which is bounded variation on $[a,b]$ for which 
$$\int_a^bfdg=\|f\|_{max}\text{    and   } TV(f)=1$$

---

**Update**

change $TV(f)=1$ to $TV(g)=1$,

BTW, this is a problem in Royden's real analysis book, see [Errata](http://people.ufpr.br/~jrrb/RoydenFitz.pdf)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let $t \in [a,b]$ be such that $\|f\|_\infty = |f(t)|$.

If $t<1$, let $h = 1_{(t,1]}$, if $t=1$, let $h=1_{\{1\}}$.

Then $\int f dh = f(t)$.

If $f(t) \ge 0$, let $g=h$ otherwise let $g = -h$.

It is straightforward to check that $TV(g) = 1$.

Comment: what about condition $TV(f)=1$?

Comment: I presume you mean $TV(g)$? The function $f$ is given.

Comment: You are right.  Thank you